# Using を/に+伴う　and meaning of 後接させる (+ 現場指示 and 文脈指示)

Tags: grammar, words, meaning

Here is the sentence (from the 日本語文法ハンドブック :

> 疑問詞が　「が」　「を」　以外の格助詞を伴う時はその格助詞の後にそのまま　「も」　を後接させます。
>
> My guess : When the interrogatives are accompanied by a case-marking particle other than "が" and "を","も" can be added  after that particle (without changing anything else).

1 : I don't understand why 伴う has a direct object though rikaichan says it's intransitive.
From the examples I've seen, it seems to me that 伴う can either mean to accompany or to be accompanied by in the following way :

> AがBに伴う。A accompanies B.
> AがBを伴う。A is accompanied by B.

If that's the case is it transitive/intransitive? What does it mean exactly?

2 : I can't find any definition for 後接 (こうせつ?) in any dictionary that i have except an example sentence in the 和英大辞典 which made me guess that it meant "to be suffixed by".

But then, why is it :

> 疑問詞が　「。。。」　「も」　**を** 後接 **させます**。
> The interrogatives let add も???

And not :

> 疑問詞が　「。。。」　「も」　**に** 後接 **できます**。
> The interrogatives can be suffixed by も.

Or :

> 疑問詞が　「。。。」(自分を)　「も」　**に** 後接 **されさせます**。
> The interrogatives let themselves be suffixed by も.

3 : Bonus point : Though I think I understand what they mean, I can't find any translation for 現場指示 and 文脈指示.

Is there any "official" translation for these words?

Comment: For #1, see [Is there a difference between に伴う and を伴う?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3713/78).

Comment: I believe 現場指示 and 文脈指示 are [deixis and anaphor](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/what-is-the-difference-between-anaphora-and-deixis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: see the @istrasci's comment.
In short, Bを伴うA: A B comes at the same time; Bに伴うA, A comes after B.

2: 後接する literally means "to be connected after".

```
「も」が格助に後接する -- mo comes after case markers
格助詞に「も」を後接させる -- put mo after case markers
```

疑問詞 belongs to the first clause.

```
疑問詞が「が」「を」以外の格助詞を伴う時は
When question words are followed by case markers other than ga or wo,
その格助詞の後にそのまま「も」を後接させます。
one simply puts mo after the case marker.
```

3: I don't know if there is any *offical* translation, but I think *place deixis* and *discourse deixis* would be fine.

I saw some people use "spatial demonstratives", "anaphoric references" for the English titles of their Japanese papers as well.

Comment: Thanks, it's a lot clearer now, however, I see the transformation from an intransitive form to a transitive one by adding させる, but who becomes the subject then? If it's the reader, then shouldn't the imperative be used (like in your translation) 後接させてください? Or is the subject someone undefined : _When question words are followed by case markers other than ga or wo, **One** simply puts mot after the case marker?_

Comment: @Alox, Yes, a subject is always required to be grammatical in English. Actually the subject is unspecific group of people, so *one*, *we* and *you* would all be fine. It's a little hard to explain, but I think it's a way to express something like **common practice**, like describing cooking procedures. Only in this situation, we use active forms rather than passive forms in Japanese. Other examples include ～という/読む/呼ぶ, (we name it, read it, call it). If you use passive forms, then it's just an objective observation, not a rule (of thumb). I don't know how to convey this sense in English.

Comment: Ok, that was the active form that was disturbing me the most (and why I was thinking about the sentence backwards with 疑問詞 as the subject of 後接させる). Thanks a lot.